# ORA-0675:package or function ORG_SPGETTYPE is in an invalid state

Tags: oracle, plsql, eclipse-plugin, oracle10g

```
PROCEDURE ORG_spGetType
(
  v_TypeId IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL 

)
AS

BEGIN


      SELECT * 
        FROM ORG_Type 
        WHERE  TypeId =  v_TypeId ;
END;
```

While Running above proceedure in oracle10g usinq eclipse platform  sql editor getting error like "ORA-0675:package or function ORG_SPGETTYPE is in an invalid state"

Answer (score 2):

That's not much of a surprise; that procedure is invalid. When compiling a procedure or any other PL/SQL block you should check whether it's compiled correctly.

If you're compiling on the command line, i.e. in SQL*Plus you can use the [SHOW](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve041.htm#SQPUG124) command and use the ERRORS variable, which:

> displays the line and column number of the error (LINE/COL) as well as the error itself (ERROR).

After you've compiled the procedure type the following:

```
show errors
```

Alternatively, you can use the [USER_ERRORS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1086.htm#sthref1187) system view which will show you a list of all errors, which the schema you're in can see.

```
select *
  from user_errors
 where name = 'ORG_SPGETTYPE'
```

The actual reason for your error is that you cannot simply SELECT in PL/SQL. If you do you're not giving PL/SQL the ability to use the results of your SELECT statement in any way and so it won't allow you to do so. If you're selecting something you *need* to do something with it; what that something is is up to you.

There are numerous ways of doing this but let's say the table ORG_TYPE is unique on the column TYPEID and you want to return one column as an OUT parameter. Your procedure would then look like this:

```
create or replace procedure org_spgettype ( 
      P_typeid in org_type.type_id%type
    , P_some_column out org_type.some_column%type
      ) is

begin

   select some_column into P_some_column     
     from org_type 
    where typeid = P_typeid;

end;
/
show errors
```

Please note a number of things:

1. There doesn't seem to be any need for the DEFAULT NULL if this is your primary key; it can't be NULL so you don't want to allow this possibility.
2. I've declared your parameters as the type of the column; this enables you to change the column without having to recode everything.

There is so much more to explain about all of this (exceptions for a start) so I would highly recommend taking some basic tutorials first or asking a colleague/friend for help.

Answer (score 2):

You would have a 'compiled with warnings' message when creating the procedure. You can query the `user_errors` view to see what problems are reported for your peocedure. You will see something like 'PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement', because you are not selecting into something.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm) shows how to do that. You need to declare variables to select into. In this case you could declare a [`rowtype`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#autoId42) variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ORG_spGetType (v_TypeId IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL) AS
  l_org_type org_type%rowtype;
BEGIN
  SELECT * 
    INTO l_org_type
    FROM ORG_Type 
    WHERE  TypeId =  v_TypeId ;

    -- do something with l_org_type
END;
/
```

Note that this can get a `no_data_found` exception if there are no matching rows, or `too_many_rows` if there are multiple matches for the passed ID.

But it isn't clear what you're planning to do with the retrieved data. This currently does nothing at all with it, it's just selected and then forgotten. The name of the procedure suggests you want to return all or part of the data from the table to the caller. If it's only one field value then this should probably be a function rather than a procedure. Or you could add `out` parameters to put the values into (as Ben shows), or return a refcursor. Depends what you need.

The `default null`, however, *maybe* suggests you sometimes expect more than one result, maybe the whole table if no value is passed - though your `where` clause won't find anything if `v_typeid` is null.

Comment: Snap(ish)! You can tell it's between 8 and 9am UK time :-).

Comment: We've just emphasised different things rather than "better"; thank you for the edit.